# Changing column list width for Box Style view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, css

This is more of a solution which I have come across in trying to solve a small issue - adjusting the column width of the Boxed style view. A simple bit of CSS in a CEWP. Does anyone know if this break the columns in an unexpected way?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-stylelabel {
    width:50%;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-variant:small-caps;
}
     .ms-stylebody{
    width:50%}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with 'break' you mean break functionality, the answer is no.

If you mean line-breaks or something, look into CSS: `overflow` , `word-break`

You might also want to add:

```
.ms-listviewtable tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}
```